# a~zを簡潔に入力する方法

Tags: python3

アルファベットが'a' = '1', 'b' = '2' ...z = '26'に出力されるような関数を作りました。
- 記号は無視
- 大文字は小文字に変換

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    a_z = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    y = list(text.lower())
    answer = []
    for x in y:
        for p,num in zip(a_z, range(26)):
            if not x.isalpha()
                break
            elif p == x:
                answer.append(str((num + 1)))
                break
    return " ".join(answer)

print(alphabet_position('who are you man!'))
# 23 8 15 1 18 5 25 15 21 13 1 14
```

お尋ねしたいのが、
・a-zが冗長でタイプミスも起こるのでもっと簡潔に表現できないか
ということです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string モジュールに string.lowercase が定義されていますので([string: Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html))、それと `index()` を使うと以下の様にも書くことができます。

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def alphabet_position(text):
  return [
    ascii_lowercase.index(c) + 1 for c in text.lower()
    if c in ascii_lowercase
  ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(alphabet_position('Who are you man!'))

=>    
[23, 8, 15, 1, 18, 5, 25, 15, 21, 13, 1, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

組み込み関数[`ord`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#ord)が使えそうです。

```py
def alphabet_position(text):
  answer = []
  ofs = ord('a') - 1
  for c in text.lower():
    if c.isalpha():
      answer.append(str(ord(c)-ofs))
  return ' '.join(answer)

print(alphabet_position('who are you man!'))
```